# Is it OK to seal data to TPM SRK directly?

Tags: encryption, trusted-computing, tpm

In reviewing various TPM programs and libraries, I have noticed that
when sealing data to the TPM, a new key is always created (wrapped by
the SRK), and that new key is loaded and used in the seal operation.  When unsealing,
the sub-key must first be loaded (unwrapped) before the unseal operation
can be performed.

Is it necessary to create a new key for each sealing operation, or
can the SRK be used directly to seal data?  If it is necessary, what are
the security and/or practical reasons why it is necessary?

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it is possible as a sealing operation needs a Storage Key, and a SRK is a Storage Key. In pratice, it is not implemented as usually the SRK is given the WKS(Well-known-Secret = 20 bytes of 0x0) or an empty password, so concerning the security dimension, it is not a good idea.

EDIT: I just checked in TrouSerS, [`tpm_sealdata`](https://sourceforge.net/p/trousers/tpm-tools/ci/master/tree/src/cmds/tpm_sealdata.c#l254) creates a key with[`keyCreateKey`](https://sourceforge.net/p/trousers/mailman/message/5096214/) which calls [`Tspi_Key_CreateKey`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tspi_key_createkey) which needs a wrapping key. `tpm_sealdata` calls keyCreateKey with the SRK. So if you use TPM 1.2 and TrouSerS, you need a wrapper, and this wrapper is the SRK. I don’t know how it is done for the TPM 2.0